# bundle exec rspec spec/ => invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec/` on my Windows 7 64bit system, I receive the following error:

```
invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32] (installed in c:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby192), and bundler 1.0.15 (installed as a ruby gem).

Any clues on how to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bundler doesn't like the fact that Ruby's path contains spaces.

To fix the problem, I edited runtime.rb (in %RUBYDIR%\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\bundler-1.0.15\lib\bundler), changing line 147 (inside `def setup_environment`) from:

```
rubyopt.unshift "-I#{File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)}"
```

to:

```
rubyopt.unshift "\"-I#{File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)}\""
```

This surrounds the entire option with quotes so that Ruby interprets it as a single option.

Comment: This ~~really should go~~ has been sent to the Bundler guys.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I've gotten so many error just because I decided to install rails in my "Program Files" folder.

Comment: I have bundler 1.94 and the code in setup_environment changed, but I still get the error (have a Ruby path with spaces). Is there a new fix?